# crop image on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, canvas, crop

I need to fix a cropping canvas above an image, the image should be zoomable and draggable but canvas must be fixed, this needs to be implemented for mobile site. For demo, you can refer cropping functionality of facebook app, but I need the same functionality for mobile site.

Zoom and drag should be touch-enable not through buttons.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Stack Overflow isn't just a bunch of people that will code for free for you.

Comment: I tried interactjs, but integrating different features like enlarging and dragging was not working smoothly.

Comment: Then I tried http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/ but fixing canvas above image using css is not possible.